# Возврат указателя на локальную переменную C++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Есть два варианта функции. Почему не работает первый - понятно, но почему тогда срабатывает второй вариант?

Первый:

```
int* f() {
   int b = 10;
   return &b;
}
```

Второй:

```
int* f() {
   int b = 10;
   int* a = &b;
   return a;
}
```

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы понимаете, почему так делать нельзя, да?

Comment: Извините, допустил ошибку. Не b, а &b

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "срабатывает"? Оба варианта нерабочие.

Comment: У нас есть две альтернативы. Либо автор вопроса не понимает, почему возвращать ссылку на локальную переменную нельзя, и кто-то должен ему объяснить. Либо автор вопроса понимает, что он делает, и тогда смысл слова «работает» неясен.

Comment: Я понимаю, что указатель на локальную переменную нельзя возвращать и поэтому не работает первый вариант. Однако, если написать
    int* a = &b;
    return a;
Компилятор не ругается и программа выдает правильный ответ. И вопрос почему это работает

Comment: @VladD с первой альтернативой - понятно. Какая вторая?

Comment: @Igor: Как выяснилось, автор вопроса понимает, что так делать нельзя, но не понимает, почему код работает при нарушении правил.

Comment: @VladD, ну, не то что бы *так делать нельзя*. Делать-то можно, только надо хорошо понимать, *что именно мы хотим дальше с этим адресом сделать*.

Comment: @avp: Угу. Но это уже следующий уровень: этот указатель, и производные от него, нельзя _разыменовывать_. Или можно, если мы в точности знаем бинарный лэйаут скомпилированной функции (что не так уж и просто при хотя бы `-O2`), и сумеем уговорить компилятор не заметить UB и не воспользоваться им.

Comment: @VladD,точно, без знания во что компилируется код лучше по таким указателям не ходить. Обычно это нужно, чтобы получить указатель стека, пройтись по фреймам, посмотреть на сохраняемые регистры...

Comment: @VladD, "этот указатель, и производные от него, нельзя _разыменовывать_". Это же C++ :). Указатель на локальную переменную после окончания времени жизни этой локальной переменной, вообще говоря, не стоит даже копировать. [basic.stc / 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4).

Comment: @wololo: Ааааа! «_Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior._» Мм-да, даже использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Окей, в вашем вопросе на самом деле несколько вопросов.

Во-первых, ваш код, оба его варианта, очевидно неверен, так как локальные переменные умирают вместе с фреймом стека функции, в которой они определены.

Почему первый вариант не компилируется? Компилятор, очевидно, видит, что вы возвращаете указатель на локальную переменную, и выдаёт ошибку (или, скорее всего, предупреждение).

Почему же тогда второй вариант компилируется? Дело в том, что компилятор не обязан ловить вас за руку каждый раз, когда вы совершаете ошибку. Он не будет рассматривать то, откуда пришли значения во всех переменных, которые вы возвращаете. Если в первом случае он вам помог (потому что это было легко), то во втором он просто решил этого не делать (потому что ему пришлось бы анализировать, откуда пришло значение переменной `a`). C++ — язык для взрослых, он считает, что программист читал документацию, понимает, что он делает, и компилятор не надоедает программисту излишними предупреждениями.

Да, а почему второй вариант работает? А случайно. У вас в стеке случайно ничего не затёрло переменную, расположенную в ничьей памяти. Вот эту самую ничью память случайно никто не забрал. А мог забрать в любой момент. Просто не делайте так, иначе никаких гарантий нормальной работы программы нет.

Если делать по правилам, программа будет работать. Если делать не по правилам, она может работать, а может и нет.

Answer (score 0):

Повезло. У Вас переменная `a` хранится в стеке. Вы возвращаете адрес на стек из функции. Что лежит по этому адресу после выхода из функции - неизвестно никому. В данном случае, так совпало, что значение не было затерто

Answer (score -2):

Потому что вы присваивание указателю значение 10.

Comment: Извините, то ли я был сонный, то ли мобильный не прогрузил, но мне показалось, что во втором случае было:

int* a = b;